# Populating select box with Ajax and Jquery from queryset in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I have a bunch of code that I think is supposed to populate a "category" select box from the value in another "subject" select box.

views.py

```
def get_categories(request, subject_id):
    subject = Subject.objects.get(pk=subject_id)
    categories = subject.category_set.all()
    category_dict = {}
    for cat in categories:
        category_dict[cat.id] = cat.name
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(category_dict), content_type="application/json")
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^get_categories/(?P<subject_id>\d+)/$', views.get_categories, name='get_categories'),
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select[name=subject]').change(function(){
        subject_id = $(this).val();
        request_url = '/get_categories/' + subject_id + '/';
        $.ajax({
            url: request_url,
            success: function(data){
                $.each(data[0], function(key, value){
                    $('select[name=category]').append('<option value="' + this.key + '">' + this.value +'</option>');
                });
            }
        })
    })
});
```

the request is passing the json data as far as I can tell,
Javascript is giving an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

I tired changing data[0] to data and that removed the error but all the fields showed up as undefined in the select box.

Answer (score 2):

If your JSON is valid, you should use `data` (not `data[0]`) and your problem is most likely here:

```
$('select[name=category]').append('<option value="' + this.key + '">' + this.value +'</option>');
```

The `this` keyword in $.each returns the value, but as an object. See:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

> The value can also be accessed through the this keyword, but
>   Javascript will always wrap the this value as an Object even if it is
>   a simple string or number value.

So `this.key` and `this.value` will give you `undefined`.

This should work (again, assuming your JSON is valid):

```
success: function(data){
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
        $('select[name=category]').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value +'</option>');
    });
}
```

Comment: Note also that it's really inefficient to query the select each time. Do it once, before the each loop, store it in a local variable and reference it from there inside the loop.